# org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Got exception: java.io.IOException Failed to get server trash configuration

Tags: hiveql

Getting following error while trying to drop partition on Hive: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Got exception: java.io.IOException Failed to get server trash configuration

Comment: Could you explain when this is happening? Where does it happen in the code? Do you have a full stack trace? Something else that could help us identify the problem? Give us some more information..

Comment: This has happened when I was trying to drop partition. The full command is given below: alter table test1 drop partition (dt='2015-01-01');